# Relocation mechanism for windows drivers

Tags: kernel, static-linking, drivers, segments, relocation

I'm trying to understand a little bit the loading process of kernel drivers.
As far as I know, kernel drivers are loaded in the upper memory area ( > 0x80000000 on win32) indeed their base adress is not known at compile time.
I've looked accros some systems drivers header's data and it seems their is no relocation directory.

So how the kernel manage to load them properly?
Or driver's code is position independant ? I don't think so because of the presence of various data segment.

Thank you !